# Querying enter key does not work in Android soft keyboards

Tags: android, keyboard, enter, soft-keyboard

I need to listen to keypresses for a kind of terminal emulation. So I do not have any `EditText`. But I successfully spawn the soft keyboard by

```
public class  Click  implements View.OnClickListener
  {
    @Override
    public void  onClick (View view)
      {
        CursorText  terminal = (CursorText) findViewById (R.id.term_window);
        InputMethodManager  manager;
        manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        manager.showSoftInput (terminal, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
      }
  }
```

The variable `terminal` here is an instance of a custom class `CursorText` that is derived from `TextView`. It has the attribute `android:textIsSelectable="true"` so that it accepts clicks. Otherwise it has `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|flagForceAscii"`, but these do not seem to have any detrimental effect.

My problem is now receiving the keystrokes. Surveying the API documentation it looks as if there were no reliable way, as in any pertinent piece of documentation it is stated that the classes and methods it is describing only works for hardware keyboards! But there must be a way.

I have tried a number of approaches, with `onKeyListener`, `onKeyPreIme`, etc., most do not react at all. For instance `onKeyPreIme` needs to be overridden in a class derived from `View`, in my case the obvious choice is the class `terminal` is an instance of. It is not an `EditText`, and maybe that's the reason `onKeyPreIme` never gets called. I believe I cannot use a `TextWatcher` in my case for the same reason.

The best result up to now is from overriding `onKeyDown` in the Activity. This method gets called for almost every key, including Backspace; the one exception being the one most-important key, the Enter (Return) key. I have a feeling that some other listener method is called before mine and handles, but does not pass on, the Enter key events. I do not know though how to find out.

The other problem I have with `onKeyDown` is that it does not generate auto-repeat on holding a key. Since it seems to only report `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, but no `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`, I cannot create auto-repeat myself.

I think I could live without auto-repeat, but having no Enter key is a show-stopper. So how do I unlock Enter key events? What prevents `onKeyDown` from being called when I press Enter? Or alternatively, should I go for an entirely different way of listening to keystrokes?

BTW. I'm testing on Lollipop and Kitkat, both CM on real hardware and vintage-Google-Android on the emulator, trying to support Jelly Bean and later.

Answer (score 0):

SOftkeyboards rarely create key events.  They usually work by invoking inputConnection.commitText, which takes an entire string at a time.  To do what you want, you'd need to tie the InputMethod to a view and override the view's onCreateInputConnection to return a custom InputConnection that can handle commitText properly.